# Using SSL certificate in database

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, security, database-security

I was exploring SSL certificates and its advantages. There I came across using SSL certificate for Database connection. I am confused with why we need secure connection with database. Since if secure connection is established between client and server, anyway server is what's going to connect and fetch from Database. Why do we need secure connection with database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need SSL when the connection method is not secure, such as attaching to a remote database over the Internet. It's probably not a bad idea in general even for an internal application if there is any risk that someone, such as employee, may be able to intercept and either view the data in plaintext or do a MITM attack and they're not otherwise authorized to completely control the database.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea of SSL is to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks and to make sure the remote server is really who they say they are.

Comment: How about mutual authentication and confidentiality and integrity ?

Comment: Exactly. The main idea of SSL is {confidentiality, integrity, authentication}. Not just one or two of those.